# Use Yiinfinite-Scroll 2 times on 1 view

Tags: yii, widget, infinite-scroll, yii-extensions

I implemented the [Yii infinite-scroll](http://www.davialexandre.com.br/demos/yiinfinite_scroll).

Now I was wondering of its possible to use the widget twice in 1 view like:

```
<div id="demo-area1">
    <div class="items">
        <div class="messages">
            <?php foreach($provider->getData() as $i => $item): ?>
                <div class="item">
                    <?php echo CHtml::image($item["ImageUrl"]); ?>
                    <p class="author"><?php echo $item["User"]; ?></p>
                    <p class="message"><?php echo $item["Message"]; ?></p>
                    <p class="publication_date"><?php echo Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime($item["Time"]); ?></p>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <?php $this->widget("ext.yiinfinite-scroll.YiinfiniteScroller", array(
                            "itemSelector" => "div.items1", 
                            "pages" => $provider->pagination)); ?>
    </div>
</div>

 <div id="demo-area2">
     <div class="items">
         <div class="messages">
             <?php foreach($provider->getOtherData() as $i => $item): ?>
                 <div class="item">
                     <?php echo CHtml::image($item["ImageUrl"]); ?>
                     <p class="author"><?php echo $item["User"]; ?></p>
                     <p class="message"><?php echo $item["Message"]; ?></p>
                     <p class="publication_date"><?php echo Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime($item["Time"]); ?></p>
                 </div>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
         </div>
         <?php $this->widget("ext.yiinfinite-scroll.YiinfiniteScroller", array(
                                "itemSelector" => "div.items2", 
                                "pages" => $provider->pagination)); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I use this, only the first infinite scroll works. How do I get the second to work?

Comment: Never seen Yiinifite before (but it looks good!). Can the problem be that you are using the variable `$provider` twice? Can you rename this to `$provider1` and `$provider2`?

Comment: You don't actually have divs with classes `items1` and `items2` just two divs with `items` class.